# Is there any option to use eloquent with relation based on if condition?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there any option to use eloquent with relation based on if condition.
I am trying to make an object based on if condition. please look at the blow posted code. every time the last condition object is returning. but I need the full object. if you see the code there have two objects CountryDetails and stateDetails. but this code returning only last object stateDetails. I need both CountryDetails and stateDetails.

if you see the code there have two objects CountryDetails and stateDetails. but this code returning only last object stateDetails. I need both objects CountryDetails and stateDetails.

```
  if($registrationFieldObj->country == true){
                $userDetails->with(['userMeta'=>function($query){
                    $query->with(['CountryDetails'=>function($query2){
                        $query2->select('id','country_name');
                    }]);
                }]);
            }

            if($registrationFieldObj->state == true){
                $userDetails->with(['userMeta'=>function($query){
                    $query->with(['stateDetails'=>function($query2){
                        $query2->select('id','country_id','state_name');
                    }]);
                }]);
            }
{   
     "has_error": 0,
        "msg": "Successfully Logged in",
        "api_token": "ey8S7XN3vdNgFravuw6Zmt8H3n2ol2UX1GA9q4l7XdRcitQymZ7ETv2W4lAk",
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jhon Smith",
            "email": "jhon@yopmail.com",
            "phone": "9123378019",
            "usertype": "APP",
            "profile_pic": "no_profile_img.png",
            "status": "A",
            "created_at": "2019-07-31 05:17:34",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-08 07:36:30",
            "user_meta": {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 2,
                "address": "Kolkata",
                "country_id": 101,
                "state_id": 39,
                "city_id": 5226,
                "pincode": "700001",
                "device_id": 458945132565,
                "device_token": "fsas576dfsbsfjn6qe7q",
                "device_type": "A",
                "updated_at": "2019-08-07 13:03:10",
                "created_at": null,
                "state_details": {
                    "id": 39,
                    "country_id": 101,
                    "state_name": "Uttarakhand"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$registrationFieldObj->country` is true? did you try to use `dd($registrationFieldObj->country);` to see if its true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the condition inside the subQuery

```
$withCoutry = $registrationFieldObj->country == true;
$withState = $registrationFieldObj->state == true;
$userDetails->with(['userMeta'=>function($query) use ($withCountry, $withState) {
    $withArray = [];
    if ($withCountry) {
        $withArray['CountryDetails'] = function($query2){
            $query2->select('id','country_name');
        } 
    }
    if ($withState) {
        $withArray['stateDetails'] = function($query2){
            $query2->select('id','country_id','state_name');
        } 
    }
    $query->with($withArray);
}]);
```

or if you get rid of the `select` part in them

```
$withCoutry = $registrationFieldObj->country == true; //just to make it simpler
$withState = $registrationFieldObj->state == true;

$withRelation = ['userMeta'];
if ($withCountry) {$withRelation[] = 'userMeta.CountryDetails';}
if ($withState) {$withRelation[] = 'userMeta.stateDetails';}

$userDetails->with($withRelation)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

there is alots of option for condition 
you can try this

```
if($registrationFieldObj->has('country')){
   //Your Logic
}
```

or

```
if(!empty($registrationFieldObj){
  //Your Logic
}
```

or

```
if(!$registrationFieldObj->isEmpty()){
 //Your Logic
}
```

Hope this helps